# Unable to add Entity Framework migrations when trying to deploy to Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio, deployment, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. This API works when it is hosted locally, however, when I attempt to deploy it on Azure, I am getting an error code 500.

I assume it is because I need to add Entity Framework migrations on my web deploy (I am deploying from Visual Studio 2022's built in Azure Publishing tool). I have successfully done this in the past, but now when I try to add migrations on deploy I get this error:

```
dotnet tool install dotnet-ef
```

> The tool package could not be restored.
> Tool 'dotnet-ef' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:
>
> - You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the -- version option to specify the version.
> - A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
> - The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
> - You mistyped the name of the tool.
>   For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool

Could it be a missing NuGet Package or outdated version of `dotnet`?

Comment: Which Azure service you want to publish to? Besides, for this issue, I suggest you could firstly try dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 6.0.0 , if this still not working , I suggest you should check  Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings > Nuget Package Manager > Package Sources. There you should have nuget.org, if not and you only have Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, well that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- The code below is a .NET Core Web API project set up with Entity Framework Core for data access.
- In the `ConfigureServices` method, services such as controllers are added, and Entity Framework Core is configured to use SQL Server with a connection string retrieved from the configuration. Thanks to @Brando Zhang for your comment. Use `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 6.0.0` to install it [locally](https://code-maze.com/net-core-web-api-ef-core-code-first/).

**Startup.cs:**

```cs
 public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddControllers();
     services.AddDbContext<CompanyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CompanyConnStr")));
 }

 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, CompanyContext context)
 {
     if (env.IsDevelopment())
     {
         app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
     }

     //Load the default employee records in the database.
     context.Seed();

     app.UseHttpsRedirection();
     app.UseRouting();
     app.UseAuthorization();

     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
     {
         endpoints.MapControllers();
     });
```

**EmployeeController:**

```cs
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
 [ApiController]
 public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
 {
     private CompanyContext _companyContext;

     public EmployeeController(CompanyContext companyContext)
     {
         _companyContext = companyContext;
     }

     // GET: api/<EmployeeController>
     [HttpGet]
     public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
     {
         return _companyContext.Employees;
     }

     // GET api/<EmployeeController>/5
     [HttpGet("{id}")]
     public Employee Get(int id)
     {
         return _companyContext.Employees.FirstOrDefault(s => s.EmployeeId == id);
     }

     // POST api/<EmployeeController>
     [HttpPost]
     public void Post([FromBody] Employee value)
     {
         _companyContext.Employees.Add(value);
         _companyContext.SaveChanges();
     }

     // PUT api/<EmployeeController>/5
     [HttpPut("{id}")]
     public void Put(int id, [FromBody] Employee value)
     {
         var employee = _companyContext.Employees.FirstOrDefault(s => s.EmployeeId == id);
         if (employee != null)
         {
             _companyContext.Entry<Employee>(employee).CurrentValues.SetValues(value);
             _companyContext.SaveChanges();
         }
     }

     // DELETE api/<EmployeeController>/5
     [HttpDelete("{id}")]
     public void Delete(int id)
     {
         var student = _companyContext.Employees.FirstOrDefault(s => s.EmployeeId == id);
         if (student != null)
         {
             _companyContext.Employees.Remove(student);
             _companyContext.SaveChanges();
         }
     }
 }
```

**CompanyContext.cs:**

```cs
 public class CompanyContext
     : DbContext
 {
     public CompanyContext(DbContextOptions options)
         : base(options)
     {

     }

     public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
 }
```

[image]
Local:
[image]

[image]

[image]

**Azure:**

[image]